# How to associate event to a spinner selection

Tags: java, android

I've created a spinner for my application. This is the code in the main.xml

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sMenu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:prompt="@string/base"
    />
```

and in my main class

```
    String [] base = {"Decimale", "Binaria", "Ottale", "Esadecimale"};
    Spinner s1;
    s1 = (Spinner) findViewById (R.id.sMenu);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.base, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The program converts a number in binary, decimal, octal, hexadecimal. I want to associated some events to the spinner. For example, if I select in the spinner binary, in the edit text I can put only binary numbers. In which way I can associate this event to the spinner?

Comment: What did you try? Did you even try to find a solution before pasting that code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id3) {
    final String b = adapter.getItem(position);
        // based on b you change the property inputType of your EditText
        // for instance, if b is 'deciaml' you set as inputType 'numberDecimal'
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

Comment: but in which way can indicate the position?

Comment: the position is a parameter passed by the framework in the method

... onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id3)...

Comment: but how can i associate the inputtype binary for example, with the string b?

Comment: if ("Decimale".equals(b)). There is no other way unless you compare the position if (position == 0), but in this last case if then you move the set of values to arrays.xml you can't anymore.